# htaccess redirect requests to index.php with former paths as query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i am trying to use a htaccess file to redirect (not rewrite) all requests (except css, js and images) to my index.php file and pass the former paths as query string.

example.de/path/test -> example.de?path1=path&path2=test

I have already looked here for some answers, but they all used rewrite

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

Original URL:

http://www.example.com/index.php?id=100

Desired destination URL:

http://www.example.com/100/

.htaccess syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

You can explore further over here:

https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489